# How does C++ linker know what .cpp files to use

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

**I am a C++ learner and I came across a concept of separating code into multiple files to speed up compiling process on bigger projects.**

However what the book doesn't tell me and I have tried to find it in other books and on the web, but with no luck is how does linker (during compilation) knows what files to include.

When I make new file I connect its header to the main file with `#include "newfile.h"`, however in this header I don't write where to find definitions of functions.

So how I imagine the process is that it starts in the main file and there it finds "connections" to other files. The question is how it finds those .cpp files that as far as I see don't need to be named the same as its header file.

**Exmple:**

Main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "krneki_H.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
 krneki1();
 krneki2();
 krneki3();
}
```

**And header file:**

```
void krneki1();
void krneki2();
void krneki3();
```

**And new .cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "krneki_H.h"

using namespace std;

void krneki1() {
cout<<"Krneki1"<<endl;}

void krneki2() {
cout<<"Krneki2"<<endl;}

void krneki3() {
cout<<"Krneki3"<<endl;}
```

**Notice that there is no indication to use second cpp file. It just knows to use it. Does it search all .cpp files in the map?**

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is a different language!

Comment: It doesn't know anything. You tell it which files to link together.

Comment: The linker doesn't use the source code at all. The programmer must tell the linker which files it needs, but they are compiled binary files, not `.cpp` or `.h` files..

Comment: I have wondered about this myself. As I understand it all .cpp files in your specified directories are compiled (compilation units). The `#include` directives include the files from headers as if you typed them in at that line. Finally the linker links the function calls and looks for `main` to put at as first instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It doesn't just know to use it. In your example, if you compile with `main.cpp` and without that new cpp file, you'll get an "undefined reference" error.

What happens is that you're using a fancy IDE that automatically compiles all cpp files. It includes them all by default in your makefile.

I recommend that you try to design a makefile from scratch, and see for yourself how you'll get that "undefined reference" error if you don't include the cpp file that has the implementations of your functions.

Answer (score 8):

You *compile* both `.cpp` files using `gcc -c` or a similar command line, and then pass both of the `.o` files produced to the linker. The linker does not magically figure out that you want to compile another `.cpp` file.

For example

```
gcc -c main.cpp -o main.o           # compile
gcc -c krneki_H.cpp -o krneki_H.o   # compile
gcc main.o krneki_H.o -o main       # link
```

Your IDE may take care of these details automatically, in which case it compiles all `.cpp` files you added to your project, then links all the `.o` files produced by the compilation step.